Vuex don't change array after get date from back
I have been struggling for several days with the task of saving and changing the array in Vuex when receiving data in the back.
I found similar problems but their solution did not help.
actions.js
import http from "@/assets/api.js";
export default {
  async getDate(context, payload) {
    const response = await http
      .get(`/dates/limit/?first=${payload.first}&rows=${payload.rows}`, token)
      .catch((error) => {
        const nError = new Error(
          error.response.data.detail || "Error get date"
        );
        throw nError;
      });
    context.commit("GetDate", response.date);
  },
  async UpdateDate(context, payload) {
    const date = {
      name: payload.name,
    };
    const servers = context.getters.showDates
    const index = servers.findIndex((el) => el.id === payload.id)
    const response = await http
      .put(`/date/${payload.id}`, date)
      .catch((error) => {
        const nerror = new Error(error.response.data.detail || 'Fail to Update')
        throw nerror
      })
    context.commit('UpdateDate', response.data)
    return response.statusText
  },
}

getters.js
export default{
  showDates(state){
      return state.dates
  },
}

index.js
import mutations from './mutations.js'
import actions from './actions.js'
import getters from './getters.js'

export default{
    state(){
        return{
            dates:[],
        }
    },
    mutations,
    getters,
    actions
}


mutations.js
export default {
  GetDate(state, payload) {
    state.dates= payload;
    //state.dates= [...payload];
  },
}


And in page
<script setup>
import {computed} from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
const store = useStore();
const contextDate = computed(() => {
  try {
    return store.getters.showDates;
  } catch (e: any) {
    showToast(e, notification.error);
  }
});
</script>

When chnage mutations in
    // const TaskCopy = state.agents.map(function(element, index) {
    //   console.log(element)
    //   console.log(index)
    //      if(index === payload.id){
    //        element = payload
    //      }
    //     return TaskCopy;
    //   });

Show error and update dates.
Package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "6.2.95",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.2",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.8",
    "vuetify-sonner": "^0.3.19",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/types": "^7.24.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.25",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.71.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2",
    "unplugin-fonts": "^1.1.1",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.26.0",
    "vite": "^5.1.5",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.6"
  }

I found similar problems but their solution did not help.
ADD
response from the server
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "id_user": 1,
  "id_dates_r": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestUser",
    "descr": "2",
     "created_at": "2024-06-30T17:59:49.669Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-06-30T17:59:49.669Z"
  },
  "dates_r": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestDatesRecord",
    "url": "3",
    "created_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z"
  }
}

Array in the store
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
        "id_user": 1,
        "id_dates_r": 2,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User2",
            "descr": "1",
            "created_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z"
        },
        "dates_r": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "test2",
            "url": "2",
            "created_at": "2024-07-01T01:45:50.946Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-01T01:45:50.946Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "id_user": 2,
        "id_dates_r": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User2",
            "descr": "1",
            "created_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z"
        },
        "dates_r": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TestDatesRecord",
            "url": "3",
            "created_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z"
        }
    },
    
]

This part is changing
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "id_user": 1,
  "id_dates_r": 1,

And this one doesn't change
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User2",
            "descr": "1",
            "created_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-06-30T22:20:15.255Z"
        },
        "dates_r": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TestDatesRecord",
            "url": "3",
            "created_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-06-30T18:00:06.540Z"
        }

The call occurs in the component

async function AddItem() {
  if (editedIndex.value > -1) {
    try {
      const message = await store.dispatch("UpdateDate", editedItem);
      Object.assign(contextDate.value[editedIndex.value], editedItem);
      showToast(NotificationTextDefault.fildUpdate, notification.success);
"ntcn");
    } catch (e: any) {
      showToast(e, notification.error);
    }
  } else {
     try {
       await store.dispatch("AddDate", editedItem);
      showToast(NotificationTextDefault.fildCreate, notification.success);
     } catch (e: any) {
       showToast(e, notification.error);
     }
  }
  close();
}


If this code is copied directly from your code base, then you have a typo in snippet #4 from your question: <sctipt setup>.

@AdrianWiik
Sorry, where is typo?I don't see this typo(
This cod may work with this typo? It's just that the code works(

@AdrianWiik import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex"; const store = useStore(); forgot to add an example. this is present in the code

The typo is directly below the text "And in page". If you can't find it, use Ctrl+F to search.

@AdrianWiik I thought that inside the block xD

It's not clear how your code works within the context of your app. Please explain how the code is supposed to work and what debugging you've done.  We don't know how/if any store action is being called.  Does the API call return successfully?  Does response.data have a value?  Unless we're looking for syntax error then code only tells half the story, we need explanation for how it's used and how it behaves step by step when it runs.

@yoduh Add informations
